# Prolog search key/value list and output a list of values

Tags: prolog

I'm once again stuck with a pretty simple Prolog task. I want to define a predicate `kv_search/3` that takes a key/value list such as `[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3],[d,4],[e,8],[a,9],[b,10]]` as a first argument, a key as second and outputs a list of all values with that key in the third argument.

My current approach looks like this:

```
kv_find([[K,V|_]|Rest], K, Result) :- 
    kv_find(Rest, K, [V|Result]).

kv_find([[Ks,_|_]|Rest], K, Result) :-
    Ks \= K ,
    kv_find(Rest, K, Result).

kv_find([], _, _).
```

The problem with this solution is however that it just outputs true or false instead of printing the missing parameter.

E.g. the following query result in `true` instead of my expected result of `B=[1, 9]`:

```
kv_find([[a,1],[b,2],[c,3],[d,4],[e,8],[a,9],[b,10]], a, B).
```

If the key is not present in the list I want to output an empty list.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your base case?  For example, what should `kv_find([],a,X)` bind to `X` (if anything)?

Comment: For this task we can assume that the first parameter is a valid key/value list in the form I showed. But your example could result in `X=[]`.

Comment: "Could"?  Suggesting could be something else?  And your code does not behave this way.

Comment: True. But I didn't think of this case until now because my excercise does not specify this case.

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti "_**my excercise does not specify this case.**_" well thats not true when you have recursion you need always think the right base case since a wrong base case could lead to a wrong overall predicate...

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti: You didn't think of the base case, but you wrote code for it?  That rarely ends well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your base case is wrong, you need to write:

```
kv_find([], _, []).
```

Since with empty list only an empty output list should succeed.

Then another problem in your solution is that you are writing:

```
kv_find([[K,V|_]|Rest], K, Result) :- 
    kv_find(Rest, K, [V|Result]).
```

While you should write something like:

```
kv_find([[K,V|_]|Rest], K, [V | Result]) :- 
    kv_find(Rest, K, Result).
```

And the above rule with the wrong base case made your predicate always succeed for any third list.

Moreover with a few changes I would write something like:

```
kv_find([[K,V]|Rest], K, [V|Result]) :- 
    kv_find(Rest, K, Result).

kv_find([[Ks,_]|Rest], K, Result) :-
    dif(Ks, K) ,
    kv_find(Rest, K, Result).

kv_find([], _, []).
```